# Count number of lowercase letters

Tags: mips

So I have created this program to count the number of lowercase letters in a string. The problem I am having is that when I reach the end of the string and the `nl` character is reached, the line `beq $t0, $t1, end` is not being executed; it just continues indefinitely. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
.data
msg1: .word 0:24
.text
.globl main
main:
    addu $s0, $0, $ra
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, msg1
    la $a1, 100
    syscall
loop:
    lb $t0, 4($a0)
    li $t1, 0x0a
    beq $t0, $t1, end
continue:
    li $t1, 'a'
    blt $t0, $t1, count
    li $t1, 'z'
    bgt $t0, $t1, count     
count:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1
    j loop
end:
    li $v0, 1
    addu $a0, $t2, $0       
    syscall 
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

You compare `4($a0)` with `0x0a` on each iteration of the loop, but you never change `$a0` in the loop, so you are not advancing through your string and never look at the `\n` at the end of the string.

There also are a few other bugs in your code.

Use this at the start of your loop:

```
loop:
    lb $t0, 0($a0)
    addiu $a0, $a0, 1
    ...
```

Comment: How do I change $a0 to compare to the next character? I am having a hard time understanding MIPS